# Debugging symbols for OS X Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, chromium, debug-symbols

How can I get dSYM symbol files for release builds of Chrome on OS X?

E.g. Google kindly publish the debug symbols for their *Windows* builds on a MS symbol server (http://chromium-browser-symsrv.commondatastorage.googleapis.com) but I can't find a similar repository for the OS X builds.

Of course I can generate my own symbol files by building Chromium from source, but then the binaries won't match Google's own releases...

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not sure that it will work in your case, but I see somewhere :

> If you’re unable to download your dSYM from Xcode’s Organizer, visit
>   iTunes Connect, select “My Apps” and “Activity”. Then select the build
>   you want to download the dSYMs for and click on “Download dSYM”.